# Passing Variable from <a> tag too an Html Form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, web

I want to make a booking page for my website. There are divs which the user can click on that will open up a form that asks for their information required to book a date for the lesson, and a time slot. The problem is i do not know how to pass the time that was selected when the user clicks on the booking card( tag inside of a div)

Here is the Code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="book_card" id="Tues1" style="visibility: <?=$TuesV1?>">
        <a class="booklnk" href="#" id='<?=$Tues1?>'>
        <p1><?=$Tues1?></p1>
        <p2><?=$TuesA1?></p2>
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="book_card" id="Tues2" style="visibility:<?=$TuesV2?>">
        <a class="booklnk" href="#" id='<?=$Tues2?>'>
        <p1><?=$Tues2?></p1>
        <p2><?=$TuesA2?></p2>
      </a>
      </div>

PHP: 
    $ARR_BOOK = [];
    $ARR_DAYS = ['Tues', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $ARR_BOOK[] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($ARR_DAYS as $DAY) {
      ${'count'.$DAY} = 0;
      ${$DAY.'V1'} = "visible";
      ${$DAY.'A1'} = "Join The Waiting List!";
      ${$DAY.'1'} = "No Spaces Available";
    }

    foreach ($ARR_BOOK as $DATA) {
      if(in_array($DATA[0], $ARR_DAYS)){
    ${'count'.$DATA[0]} += 1;
    ${$DATA[0].${'count'.$DATA[0]}} = $DATA[1];
    ${$DATA[0].'V'.${'count'.$DATA[0]}} = "visible";
    ${$DATA[0].'A'.${'count'.$DATA[0]}} = "Available";
      }
     }
```

Comment: you need a unique identifer in the db, then when you list the items you add that identifier to the value of an input. then you can queue any action having that.

Comment: How are the timeslots stored? Add a url parmater to each href and then when they go to form you know which slot was chosen based on url

Comment: Thank you for those comments guys, in my db i do have slot ID for each one but i do not know how to pass what of the <a> tags were clicked as i have many more divs there created and so when the user fills out the form, i would like it to also send what time slot they clicked on and chose. Too the second comment, my timeslots are sotred in the DB, and in the php variable $Tues1, but the number and day changes on each of the divs, e.g. $Tues1, $Tues2, $Fri1, $Fri2, $Fri3. This all depends on what slots are available in the database to be booked.

Comment: Your `<a>` tags don't have a URL in the `href`. Are the clicks being processed using Javascript?

Comment: this single quote, double quote thing is ugly `<a class="booklnk" href="#" id='<?=$Tues1?>'>` .  Now if its a value from PHP, you wont know without javascript when a user clicks, PHP is server side.  For live interaction like that you need javascript.

Comment: Stop using variable variables, use associative arrays.

Comment: The JS that runs when you click on the anchor can use `this.id` to get the timeslot in the ID.

Comment: I second the variable variables, When I first saw this in code back in 2010 ( granted I was a noob then, that was the `$$var` version)  I thought it was a typo, its a very strange and obscure language construct, not to mention all the other issues it causes with IDE's and code readability, bugs etc.  There is hardly ever a good reason to use them aside from laziness (which isn't a good reason) all it does is cause confusion in your code..

Comment: Sorry about the double quote and sinlge quote, its a very bad habbit and i will fix it up right away. Yes the <a> tags will be proscessed by Javascript if possible. I was wondering about passing the timeslot through the ID to javascript but wasnt sure how to do that, but knowing that it would work i will look into that further, thank you for that comment!

Comment: Javascript `$('.booklnk').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); alert($(this).find('p1').text()); return false;}` or something like that.  I don't know what you mean by `i do not know how to pass the time that was selected when the user clicks on the booking card( tag inside of a div)`  What I put above will get the text of the `p1` tag inside of the `book_card` that houses the `a.booklnk` that was clicked.  I don't understand what you are trying to retrieve when clicked, but you cant do it without Javascript.  Just for example you say `tag inside of a div` but to me there are 3 tags.

Comment: Inside of the div, do you mean the `a` tag, and what information is retrieved.  As mentioned because of your variable variables, I don't know what this is `${$DAY.'V1'}` is it `TueV1`  `tueV`  or `02V1`  `TuesdayV1` etc.  Instead of being able to just look at it, I have to reference the array, run the code in my head and figure all that out.  And in the case of these `${$DATA[0].'V'.${'count'.$DATA[0]}}` its impossible for me to know, because it's tied to a database I don't know anything about,  Make sense.

Comment: $TueV1 is to turn the div visible, $Tue1 is the time slot $TueA1 is for Special message e.g. Available, or Join Waiting List

Comment: But yes it does make sense why not to use Variable Variables, its just at the time of making it, its what seems to make the most sense because it only creats variables that is needed and only runs for the minimum amount of time, but now i can see why it wouldnt be so good, Any suggestions on what i should be using instead? btw thank you for the helpful comments

Comment: Well, take it as a lesson, to write more descriptive variable names, like `$visible` then later when you look at it, 2 or 3 years from now, you will know exactly what it means.  In any case I am still not sure what value you are, trying to get,  Nor do I see any kind of form `up a form`, to me a form is `<form>` tag.  With only partial code, its impossible to figure out.

Comment: Generally, with Javascript its a simple matter of trigger an `On Click` event handler and then (what I do) is take a hidden input in the form and modify that with the value from whatever they clicked.  You can even add that data into the element when construing it `<a data-time="<?= $sometime;?> ...` then you do `$('a.booklnk').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault; var time = $(this).data('time'); });` and then just take your element `$(el).val(time)` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here as an example, using some simple jQuery and clever construction of the link to populate the data in a form:

```js
$('.booklnk').click(function(e){ 
  //prevent default link click
  e.preventDefault();
  //get the data from the link that was clicked
  var time = $(this).data('time');
  //modify the form so when the user submits it the field is sent
  //tip, you can change the input from type="text" to type="hidden"
  //so the user cannot see it, but for example purpose it's easier to show it.
  $('#my_fld').val(time);

  return false; //helps prevent double click link access
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test_form">
     <input type="text" name="my_fld" id="my_fld" value="" />
</form>

<div class="book_card" id="Tues1" >
     <a class="booklnk" href="#" data-time="2018-08-08 21:9:27" >Click Me</a>
    <!-- make you life easier by putting the data in the data attribute of the link -->
    <!-- as with any HTML this can be set serverside when building the page such as  <a class="booklnk" href="#" data-time=<?php echo $timeslot; ?>" .. -->

</div>
```

Note - this isn't a full answer as I am still confused about

- There are divs which the user can click on that will open up a form

I don't see any forms

- the user clicks on the booking card( tag inside of a div)

Which tag In which div

- the problem is i do not know how to pass the time

Where is the times (specifically)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, this is amazing. You have been such a help in this, and if I had a longer made account I would be able to upvote your reputation. I will also look into another way to stop using varible variables. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: sure, no problem